Difference between Shell and Shell32 VBA
When we declare object with DIM in VBA, at some places I find Dim objShell as Shell and sometimes code contains Dim objShell as Shell32.
What is the difference between Shell and Shell32 specifically when used in VBA code?  I tried to search on Google,  but there are numerous documentations.
I edited my query as under as comment section doesn't allow this much:
I am sorry if I have not put my question correctly. I paste hereunder a code sample from Microsoft Documentation for Folder.Getdetailsof method. Here only "Shell" is used in Declaration.
Private Sub btnGetDetailsOf_Click()
    Dim objShell  As Shell
    Dim objFolder As Folder

    Set objShell = New Shell
    Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\WINDOWS")
    
    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Dim objFolderItem As FolderItem
        Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName("clock.avi")
   
        If (Not objFolderItem Is Nothing) Then
            Dim szItem As String
            szItem = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 2)
        End If
        
        Set objFolderItem = Nothing
    End If
    
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objShell = Nothing
End Sub

Below is a second code sample in which Shell32 is used in declaration section as "Shell32.Shell"
Function GetFileAttributes(FilePath As String) As Object
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim objShell As Shell32.Shell, objFolder As Shell32.Folder
    Dim objFolderItem As Shell32.FolderItem, i As Long
    Dim strFileName As String, aName As String, aValue As String, strPath As String
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'vbTextCompare: case insensitive
    strFileName = Mid(FilePath, InStrRev(FilePath, "\") + 1)
    strPath = Left(FilePath, Len(FilePath) - Len(strFileName) - 1)
    
    Set objShell = New Shell
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(strPath)
    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(strFileName)
        
    For i = 0 To 255
        aName = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(Null, i)
        aValue = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, i)
        'list only the attributes with a value:
        If Len(aValue) > 0 Then
            dict.Add aName, aValue
            'Debug.Print i & " - " & aName & ": " & aValue
        End If
    Next i
    Set GetFileAttributes = dict
End Function

I got the above code in reply to my other query in this forum. Here Shell is declared by using Shell32.Shell.  Folder object is also defined by using "Shell32.Folder" which is not so in First sample code. Kindly guide what difference is there between them.
REGARDS

There is neither Shell nor Shell32 in the default shipment of VBA (there is the Shell function but you cannot Dim it). So what the difference is between Shell and Shell32 depends on what libraries you have referenced and what these names mean in them. If you have referenced the popular "Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation" library, shell32.dll, then Shell is the name of the class, which you can Dim as, and Shell32 is the name of the library, which you cannot Dim as, so the answer then is, the difference is that Dim objShell as Shell works and Dim objShell as Shell32 doesn't.

Kindly guide what difference is there between them - the difference is same as between Dim w As Worksheet and Dim w As Excel.Worksheet in the duplicate.
